# Failed to allocate memory, NoMemoryError

Tags: ruby

I am trying to serialize an object and save it to a Postgresql Database using ActiveRecord in ruby (without rails). I am using the following code to do so:

```
  components.keys.each do |key|
    cphash = {:training_url => components[key][:training_url],
              :klass => key.to_s, 
              :component => Marshal::dump(components[key][:component]),
              :network_id => n}
    inline = Inline.new(cphash)
    inline.save!
  end
```

However, I keep getting the error

```
failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)
```

How do I get around this. I have tried breaking the object into smaller bits (I am saving each bit in the 'each' above), but Im still getting the error. Anyone knows what gives.

Answer (score -1):

The Inline gem is for running C code within ("inline") ruby.

http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/RubyInline/

Comment: Umm, inline is not the inline gem, its a class I have written

Comment: Well the provide the source. How can you expect us to help you when you don't provide all of the code? NoMemoryError comes up for very specific reasons.